# How can one copy a matplotlib ax object

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

Instead of the following:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = [1, 2]
y = [4, 5]
ax.scatter(x, y, s=100)
```

Which looks as 
[image]

I would like to have:

```py
def plot(ax, x, y):
    ax_c = copy.deepcopy(ax)
    ax_c.scatter(x, y, s=100)
    return ax_c



fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = [1, 2]
y = [4, 5]
ax = plot(ax, x, y)
```

However, this doesn't work, with the following error:

```
NotImplementedError: TransformNode instances can not be copied. Consider using frozen() instead.
```

So, I'm wondering how I go about writing a function which takes a matplotlib `ax` as input, creates a copy of it, alters the copy, and returns it. The reason that I'd like to do so is so that I can have functions which are self-contained.

## edit

the following is not a suitable solution:

```py
def plot(ax_c, x, y):
    ax_c.scatter(x, y, s=100)
    return ax_c
```

because here the return statement could be replaced with `None` and it would still function fine.

Comment: Try the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39975898/copy-matplotlib-artist)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the following way in your function

```
def plot(ax_c, x, y):
    ax_c.scatter(x, y, s=100)
    return ax_c
```

Comment: I understand that - but here the `return` is unnecessary, you could have this function return `None` and it would do exactly the same thing